# In react, how to put jsx elements into string and then have event listener render correctly

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, jsx

I'm having problems with one one small library, and am looking for workaround where I pass it html in a string. I am having problems (is this even possible) with attaching event listener. I would like to do something like this:

```
library({
    title: `<div onChange={this.function} />`
)}
```

This renders a div but not with a working onChange. Any ideas how to proceeed?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this? Maybe give the snippet of the implementation code?

Comment: Where are you using that library({...}) ? A bit more info is needed I think. You can pass JSX inside an array and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to inject generated HTML into a div then you better start using dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute like this below:

```
function createMarkup() { 
    return <SomeJsxComponentHere />
};
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Refer: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html for more details on why this is important.

If you want a event to be emitted every time this createMarkup() function is called then you can use standard JavaScript to hook up event emitters or even better if your plan is to render a large markup that may require above normal time to render then consider making this createMarkup() a promise function, this way in the .then(..) you can do the rest of the job like updating state etc